# Is there an elegant way to foldLeft on a growing scala.collections.mutable.Queue?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, queue, mutable

I have a recursive function that I am trying to make `@tailrec` by having the inner, recursive part (`countR3`) add elements to a queue (`agenda` is a `scala.collections.mutable.Queue`). My idea is to then have the outer part of the function fold over the agenda and sum up the results.

NOTE: This *was* a homework problem, thus I don't want to post the whole code; however, making the implementation tail-recursive was *not* part of the homework.

Here is the portion of the code relevant to my question:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue

val agenda: Queue[Tuple2[Int, List[Int]]] = Queue()

@tailrec
def countR3(y: Int, x: List[Int]): Int = {
  if (y == 0) 1
  else if (x.isEmpty) 0
  else if …
  else {
    agenda.enqueue((y - x.head, x))
    countR3(y, x.tail)
  }
}
⋮
agenda.enqueue((4, List(1, 2)))
val count = agenda.foldLeft(0) {
  (count, pair) => {
    val mohr = countR3(pair._1, pair._2)
    println("count=" + count + " countR3=" + mohr)
    count + mohr
  }
}
println(agenda.mkString(" + "))
count
```

This *almost* seems to work… The problem is that it doesn't iterate over all of the items added to the agenda, yet it does process *some* of them. You can see this in the output below:

```
count=0 countR3=0
count=0 countR3=0
count=0 countR3=0
(4,List(1, 2)) + (3,List(1, 2)) + (2,List(2)) + (2,List(1, 2)) + (1,List(2)) + (0,List(2))
```

[Of the six items on the final agenda, only the first three were processed.]

I'm generally well-aware of the hazards of mutating a collection while you're iterating over it in, say, Java. But a Queue is kind of a horse of a different color. Of course, I understand I could simply write an imperative loop, like so:

```
var count = 0
while (!agenda.isEmpty) {
  val pair = agenda.dequeue()
  count += countR3(pair._1, pair._2)
}
```

This works perfectly well, but this being Scala, I am exploring to see if there is a more *functionally elegant* way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although probably not entirely idiomatic, you could try this:

```
Stream.continually({ if (agenda.isEmpty) None else Some(agenda.dequeue()) }).
    takeWhile(_.isDefined).flatten.
    map({ case (x, y) => countR3(x, y) }).
    toList.sum
```

- The `Stream.continually({ if (agenda.isEmpty) None else Some(agenda.dequeue()) })` gives you an infinite stream of queue items wrapped in `Option[Tuple2[Int, List[Int]]]`.
- Then, `takeWhile(_.isDefined)` cuts off the sequence as soon as the first `None` item is encountered, i.e. when the queue is exhausted.
- As the previous call still yields a sequence of `Option`s, we need to unwrap them with `flatten`.
- `map({ case (x, y) => countR3(x, y) })` basically applies your function to each item.
- And finally, `toList` forces the evaluation of a stream (that's what we were working with) and then `sum` calculates the sum of list's items.

I think the problem with `agenda.foldLeft` (that it processes only 'some' enqueued items) is I'd guess that it takes a (probably immutable) list of currently enqueued items, and therefore isn't affected by items that were added during the calculation.

Comment: Not exactly idiomatic, I'd agree, but it does seem like it would fit the bill of being more functionally pure. Nice answer! And interestingly, `agenda.foldLeft` was processing more than just the initially enqueued items; it didn't appear to be simply working on a copy of the initial queue. Perhaps it was stopping when the "last" item resulted in more items being added to the queue, or something like that.